# function composition type inference in haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference

In haskell, the type of `(.)` function is:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

And the type of `(.) (.)` is:

```
(.) (.) :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> (a1 -> b) -> a1 -> c
```

I am not able to deduce the result, how is this done?

Comment: Admit it, you just wanted to write `(.)(.)` on SO

Comment: @luqui You got it! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Let's go through it. First thing this function takes is `(b -> c)` (so a function from `b` to `c`), cool. By adding a pair of (redundant) parentheses:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> a -> c)
       ^-- I am b'  ^-- I am c'   -- (b' and c' not to have name clash)
```

That first part, we gave to the function (i.e. has been taken care of):

```
(.) (.) :: (a -> b') -> a -> c'
-- after substituting stuff (b' and c')
(.) (.) :: (a -> (b -> c)) -> a -> ((a1 -> b) -> a1 -> c)
                                    ^-- of course a1 /= a
-- you could eliminate redundant parentheses
(.) (.) :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> (a1 -> b) -> a1 -> c
-- wee
```

I hope this settles it. Main point is: type inference is easy to 'get' and once you get it is only a matter of substitution to reach what ghci automagically infers.
ot: we could call this quizzical operator `boobs`.